# SQL/Hive Query to Count number of rows for each day for a certain value

Tags: python, sql, hive, data-science, hiveql

I am currently working on a Python script that uses a query to extract data from our Hive Server. I am expecting an output that will filter the cardnumbers that have x or more transactions per day depending on the input for "TxnCount".

Inputs are:  DateTime1, DateTime2, MerchantID, CardNum, terminalID and TxnCount.

My Code (not working):

```
Query = "SELECT TRIM(i002_number) as CardNum, i004_amt_trxn, TRIM(i042_merch_id) as MerchantID, i043a_merch_name, TRIM(i041_pos_id) as TerminalID, \
i049_cur_trxn, i062v2_trans_id, i003_proc_code, i006_amt_bill, i051_cur_bill, amt_card, cardcurrency, ltimestamp, \
i039_rsp_cd, i018_merch_type, i043b_merch_city, i043c_merch_cnt, i022_pos_entry, i032_acquirer_id, trxntype, reasoncode, \
SUBSTRING(i002_number, 1, 6) AS issuer_bin, COUNT(i002_number) as txncount\
CASE \
    WHEN SUBSTRING(i002_number,1,1) = 5 THEN 'MasterCard' \
    WHEN SUBSTRING(i002_number,1,1) = 4 THEN 'VISA' \
END AS source \
FROM tsys.ods_authorizations \
WHERE ltimestamp >= '"+DateTime1+"' AND ltimestamp <= '"+DateTime2+"' AND i042_merch_id = "+MerchantID+" \
AND i002_number = "+CardNum+" AND i041_pos_id = "+terminalID+""
HAVING txncount >= '"+TxnCount+"'
```

Sample Expected Data (truncated):

```
CardNum         TimeStamp           TxnCount
123      2019-06-01 00:00:30.00        2   
123      2019-06-01 05:00:20.00        2
123      2019-06-03 20:00:00.00        1
456      2019-06-04 06:00:00.00        2
456      2019-06-04 00:00:10.91        2
789      2019-06-01 12:00:40.51        1
```

I think my problem here is that it cannot count per card number since I am having problems with the GROUP BY clause. Also, I have not yet split the date and time and the query would not recognize the difference between dates yet.

Comment: Just to add:
As you can see in the select part, I need to output about 20+ columns. If that's not the case then I can easily solve this by adding:

GROUP BY i002_number, DATE(ltimestamp)

Comment: How about adding simple  `GROUP BY TRIM(i002_number),ltimestamp   ` and remove everything else from SELECT condition. But if you want all columns and count, then use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  TRIM(i002_number),ltimestamp  ORDER BY  TRIM(i002_number),ltimestamp ) as CNT`. HTH

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy, This works really well thanks. I don't have enough pts to upvote an answer yet. But this is to let you know that your solution is working.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Follow up question, it doesnt work when I don't have a "HAVING" clause. What could be the solution since I also need to have this HAVING clause for the query to accept an input for TxnCount.

Comment: I this query is not following some basics. I believe, below solution from Gordon should work. If it doesnt, please add ORDER BY like this  `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i002_number, TRUNC(ltimestamp, 'DAY') ORDER BY i002_number, TRUNC(ltimestamp, 'DAY') ) as txncount`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is malformed.  You have a `COUNT()` with a bunch of other columns -- and you have no `GROUP BY`.  This is not allowed in SQL.

I would advise you to use parameters as well, rather than munging the query string.  So, you presumably want something like this.

Your results appear to want the *details* of every transaction, rather than a summary (so you have two rows with a count of "2" rather than one).  That suggests that you really want window functions:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             (CASE WHEN i002_number LIKE '5%' THEN 'MasterCard'
                   WHEN i002_number LIKE '4%' THEN 'VISA'
              END) AS source
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i002_number, TRUNC(ltimestamp, 'DAY')) as txncount
      FROM FROM tsys.ods_authorizations a
      WHERE ltimestamp >= :timestamp1 AND
            ltimestamp <= :timestamp2 AND
            i042_merch_id = :MerchantID AND
            i002_number = :CardNum AND 
            i041_pos_id = :terminalID
     ) a
WHERE txncount >= :TxnCount
```